# jquery custom sliding menu

Tags: jquery, html, css, menu

I have problem with simple jquery sliding menu, here is my code:

http://jsfiddle.net/kCK44/1/

what I wanted to achieve is the small arrow class:

```
<div class="arrow"></div>
```

to appear at the same time as the submenu div. Right now as you can see it fully appear right after the submenu is fully slided Down. Should I take the arrow div out of it's parent and show it separately? Or is there some other way It could be fixed.

thanks a lot,
S

Comment: The menu looks kinda broken and you have targeted `.submenu arrow` which can't be found since the `.arrow` is not inside the submenu, meaning that the arrow _does not_ currently slide down at any point. I would definitely put the arrow inside the `.submenu`, but I don't know how you'd want the arrow to act, so.. I don't know.

Comment: sorry, arrow should be inside submenu, here's update: http://jsfiddle.net/kCK44/3/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The element with the slideDown will always be cropped for the duration of the animation. slideDown set overflow: hidden to the element. What you need is to move the arrow completely inside the .submenu and put the menu background to the UL instead the .submenu.

Here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kCK44/8/

The updated CSS:

```
.pageNavigation .mainNavigation ul li .submenu {
   min-width: 110px;
   display: none;
   position: absolute;
   top: 33px;
   left: -10px;
   z-index: 500;
}
.submenu .arrow {
   top:0px;
   left:33px;
   position: absolute;
   z-index: 9999;
   width:25px;
   height: 23px;
   background: #33ccff;
}
.pageNavigation .mainNavigation ul li .submenu ul {
   background: #ce3102;
   text-align: left;
   list-style-position: outside;
   list-style-image: none;
   list-style-type: none;
   margin: 15px 8px 5px;
   z-index: 500;
}
```

Comment: I agree wiht nxtwrld. It seems the "arrow" is kind of out of proportion. You should consider making a unique menu image with an arrow below and placing that on list links that have a submenu. However currently it does look cropped

Comment: @strongBAD Here's a bit cleaner code, which hopefully will help you to understand one or two things ( Although I didn't make the arrow itself slide down ): http://jsfiddle.net/lollero/JxMzZ/